# Output Of a While Loop

Tags: c, while-loop

How many times the while loop is executed in the below prog if short int is of 2 bytes?

```
main()
{
int j = 1;
while(j <= 255);
{
    printf("%d",j); 
    j++;
}
return 0;
}
```

i think it should be 255 times but its not correct. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: `1,2,3,...255`. count 'em up.

Comment: `"but its not correct"` - What makes you say that?

Comment: @MarcB We both missed the `;`

Comment: Well, if you had actually tried it, and run it under a debugger, you would have been able to discern the behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

You have a semicolon at the end of your while-line. The while loop, consisting of the statement `;`, executes "infinitely" many times.